# MySqlConnection Open() don't open and no error is caught

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm hosting an Aurora MySql instance on AWS and trying to read a table from it on a Lambda function.

This is my connection string:

```
Server=xxx.xxx.xxx4.xxx; port=3306; database=thedatabase; uid=theuser; pwd=thepassword; Connect Timeout=300
```

This is the code (.Net Core 2.1):

```
    private static void GetFromDb()
    {
        LambdaLogger.Log($"Function name GetFromDb() has been called.\n");

        int counter = 0;
        try
        {
            LambdaLogger.Log($"Using {str}\n");

            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(str))
            {
                LambdaLogger.Log($"Connection is about to be opened\n");
                conn.Open();
                LambdaLogger.Log($"Connection was opened\n");

                var text = "SELECT * FROM MarketPlace.Customers";

                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(text, conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 360;
                    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    LambdaLogger.Log($"Command was issued\n");

                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        LambdaLogger.Log($"reader has rows\n");

                        products = new List<Product>();

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            counter++;
                            LambdaLogger.Log($"Reading # {counter}\n");
                            Product p = new Product();
                            p.Id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                            p.Name = reader.GetString(1);
                            products.Add(p);
                        }
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                    LambdaLogger.Log($"{counter} items readed");
                }
            } 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception($"[GetFromDb] Error {ex.ToString()}", ex);
        }
    }
```

When try to open the connection, code stops executing, no exception is caught or raised.

Log from CloudWatch:

> START RequestId: 52225968-d360-4d27-8872-305e4b92e346 Version: $LATEST
>   ...
>   ...
>   Function name GetFromDb() has been called.
>   Using Server=xxx.xxx.xxx4.xxx; port=3306; database=thedatabase; uid=theuser; pwd=thepassword; Connect Timeout=300
>   Connection is about to be opened
>   END RequestId: 52225968-d360-4d27-8872-305e4b92e346
>   REPORT RequestId: 52225968-d360-4d27-8872-305e4b92e346    Duration: 30030.17 ms   Billed Duration: 30000 ms   Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 107 MB Init Duration: 207.87 ms
>   2019-12-12T18:23:58.089Z 52225968-d360-4d27-8872-305e4b92e346 Task timed out after 30.03 seconds

I'm really stuck here. I don't have any idea of what is happening. Roles, policies, etc. are ok.
The strange thing is despite connection timeout is set to 300 seconds, it takes less the this to stop running.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry for the hundreds of log calls. it's for troubleshooting purposes

Comment: Put the try/catch inside the `using` block so you can access the connection and command. You are timing out. You could increase the timeout but if it is the connection that is timing out the problem is probably an incorrect connection string or a firewall issue.

Comment: Hi Crowcoder. I'm using the ip addres on the server token of connection string due to the MySql bug (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=97448) which don't let it connect using the nost name.

Comment: I did what you suggested and moved try/catch to inside the using(). Testing with Postman now I got 
{
    "message": "Endpoint request timed out"
}

Comment: Inspecting the Cloudwatch I saw that connection is timing out, I dont know why.

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Connection timed out xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306) ---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException: Connection timed out xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306 where xxx is the AWS rds database.

Comment: Just because you know the IP addresses doesn't mean you can get there. I'm not familiar with AWS but in Azure almost nothing can communicate to anything else without an allowed network rule.

Comment: I would bet your Lambda function doesn't have access to the VPC the Aurora database is in. When you deployed your Lambda function did you set the subnet ids and security groups fields?

Comment: @ValmirCinquini Please edit your question to include the following information: Is the Lambda function configured to use the same VPC as the Aurora database? What is the configuration of the Security Group associated with the Aurora database?

Answer (score 1):

A timeout is usually an indication of **network connectivity issues**.

Assumption:

- The AWS Lambda function is configured to use the same VPC as the Aurora instance

Your **Security Group** configurations should be:

- A **Security Group on the Lambda function** (`Lambda-SG`) — Allow all Outbound
- A **Security Group on the Aurora database** (`Aurora-SG`) — Allow inbound connections on the appropriate port (3306?) from `Lambda-SG`

That is, `Aurora-SG` specifically allows inbound traffic from `Lambda-SG`.